# sparceCheckout of subdir contents checkouts out parent folders

Tags: git

Here is what I ran:

```
git init &&
git remote add -f origin <repository-url> &&
git config core.sparseCheckout true &&
echo "app/folder/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout &&
git pull --depth=1 origin master && ls -la
```

What I expect:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

What I get:

```
app/ 
 └── folder/
       ├── file1
       ├── file2
       └── file3
```

For those curious it is skipping some files. The repository looks like:

```
root/
├── some_file
├── something_else 
└── app/ 
     ├── some_other_file
     ├── some_other_folder/
     └── folder/
           ├── file1
           ├── file2
           └── file3
```

I've looked at lots of stackoverflow answers.
**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: It's checking out exactly what you asked it to; why do you think it should work another way?

Comment: Maybe so, but it's not what I want to checkout. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I want to checkout only the contents of "folder" into the directory the command is run, and when i do git pull I only want those files to be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the good question: you said exactly what you did, exactly what you wanted to see, and exactly what you saw instead.  That's gotten to be just *so* rare.  Thank you.

---

What you want isn't really done much, it's rarer than sparse checkout which is saying a lot. There aren't any convenience commands that automate setting this up.  Fortunately, Git can do it anyway, you just have to use some core commands directly and set a few options.

To do what you want, first clean up the sparse checkout:

```
git read-tree -um `git mktree<&-`        # clean out the index and worktree
git config core.sparsecheckout false     # shut off sparse checkout
```

Now checkout your branch as if you weren't going to restructure everything:

```
git checkout -b appfolder --track origin/master
```

Now read only the subtree you want:

```
git read-tree -um @:app/folder
git commit -m 'Isolating the app/folder subtree'
```

Now tell `git merge` (and `git pull`) to do the subtree isolation every time you merge to this branch:

```
git config branch.appfolder.mergeoptions -Xsubtree=app/folder
```

And that will get you a branch set up to

> checkout only the contents of "folder" into the directory the command is run, and when i do git pull I only want those files to be updated

When/if you're merging back to master, you can specify the same `-Xsubtree=app/folder` and git will figure out that you're going the other way.

---

note: if even one full checkout is too much of a pain -- say it's got ten thousand files and you've got a crappy spinning-rust laptop drive with a 15ms seek at 5400rpm or something horrible like that -- you can avoid it by replacing the checkout above with

```
git checkout -b appfolder                      # name the current checkout
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master     # set its upstream ref
git reset --soft origin/master                 # and its parent commit
```